# Swift - Can I access SQLITE from another smartphone?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have an application in swift to manage small stores with SQLITE on my smartphone and I was thinking that another application that would be for sellers could access the same database. As if the phone was the server or the other smartphone accessed the same .sqlite file.

I looked in other topics but I didn't find anything like that and the ones I found has no answer.

Is this possible to do?

Something like the code below.

```
        var db: OpaquePointer? = nil

        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("some form or link with the address of the other smartphone")

        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK {

            print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(String(describing: fileURL.path))")

        } else {

            print("cant open database")

        }
```

Comment: It’s the wrong question really, another device shouldn’t access a database even if it was possible. Instead the communication should be on the app level so that if an app wants to get some data it would ask your app that then fetches it from the database and then sends it to the other app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not allow for more than one thread to write to the database. You would most likely run into deadlocks and timeouts trying to access it from multiple devices, even if you're only writing small amounts of data.

You may want to look into a different RDBMS such as MySQL, MariaDB, or any of the other database systems that implement a client-server model (i.e. one application reads and writes to/from the database and talks to the clients via network sockets) or implement a client-server model on top of SQLite yourself.

Comment: In the databases you mentioned, can I do it in the format I asked?

Comment: No. SQLite uses a file-based database, and to connect to that database, you open a connection to the file (which is what you're doing above). In general, with any database that you connect to by opening a file, you can't have multiple threads writing to the same file or else there is an extremely high risk of corruption. SQLite disables multiple connections from writing to the same database (file) at the same time for this reason. You need to move to a database that supports a client-server model (e.g. communicates using sockets) or implement one yourself.